# More efficient JS case swap

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Im new to JS. I'm going to be attending a JS boot camp and I'm doing some of the pre coursework. Below is a coderbyte solution. The request was:

Create a function that when passed a string will swap the cases of the string.

My solution:

```
function swapCase(someStr){
   var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

  var upperAlphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

  var idxLower = [];
  var idxUpper = [];

  someArray = someStr.split("");

  //Find out which indexes are lower case
  for(var i = 0; i<someArray.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<alphabet.length; j++){
      if(someArray[i] === alphabet[j]){
        idxLower.push(i);
      }
    }
  }

  //find out which indexes are upper case
  for(var k = 0; k<someArray.length; k++){
    for(var m = 0; m<upperAlphabet.length; m++){
      if(someArray[k] === upperAlphabet[m]){
        idxUpper.push(k);
      }
    }
  }

  //convert lower cases to upper
  for(var n = 0; n<idxLower.length; n++){
    for(var p = 0; p<someArray.length; p++){
      if(idxLower[n] === p){
        someArray[p] = someArray[p].toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  }
    //convert upper cases to lower
  for(var q = 0; q<idxUpper.length; q++){
    for(var r = 0; r<someArray.length; r++){
      if(idxUpper[q] === r){
        someArray[r] = someArray[r].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  }
  var newStr = someArray.join("");
  console.log(newStr); 
}
swapCase("Hello World Sup Bro My Name iS Richard!");

//returns hELLO wORLD sUP bRO mY nAME Is rICHARD!
```

I get that it's the antithesis of elogant. Can anyone use JS fundamentals to help me understand how to do this exercise in a more concise fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like: for every character, I want to make it Upper if it's Lower, and Lower if it's Upper.

That's very easy:

```
function swapCase(str) {
  var out = '';
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    // It's lower, or non-A-Z
    if (str[i].toLowerCase() == str[i]) {
      out += str[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    else {
      out += str[i].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return out;
}

alert(swapCase('Hello World Sup Bro My Name iS Richard!'));
```

(And the Fiddle to prove it.](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/m4mhsyuz/)

Comment: Thanks Rudie. I think that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This would work. It's a function that uses the character code to see if it is already uppercase or not. Here is the UTF-8 char code spec:http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp
Between 65 and 90 is uppercase, between 97 and 122 is lowercase.

```
var reverseCase = function(str){
    var output = '';
    var code = '';

    for(var i=0,len=str.length-1; i<=len; i++){
        code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if(code >= 65 && code <= 90){
            output+=str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
        }else if(code >=97 && code <= 122){
            output+=str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
        }else{
            output+=str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

reverseCase("Hello World Sup Bro My Name iS Richard!");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1jg4gqe1/

Comment: I think it would be even better to completely use the `ASCII` logic here. Thus, instead of using `toLowerCase()` just add 32 to the code and then use `String.fromCharCode(code)` for converting to lower case and subtract 32 in the latter case to convert to upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically same as @Moshe's answer, He was a couple minutes ahead of me.. .;)

```
function swapCase(someStr) {
    var code_A = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
    var code_Z = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0);
    var code_a = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
    var code_z = 'z'.charCodeAt(0);
    var parsedStr = '';
    for(i=0;i<someStr.length;i++) {
        code = someStr.charCodeAt(i);
        // If it's an uppercase
        if (code >=code_A && code <= code_Z) {
            code = code_a + code - code_A;
        // Or if it is a lowecase
        }else if (code >=code_a && code <= code_z) {
        code = code_A + code - code_a;
        }
        parsedStr += String.fromCharCode(code);
    }
    return parsedStr;
}
swapCase('WaszUp Brah *7&9');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary operations if you only need it to work with ASCII characters. You can toggle the fifth bit, the one responsible for the case, thanks to the  binary operator `^` (aka XOR which acts as a switch):

```
function swapCaseASCII(str) {
    var swappedCaseCharBuffer = new Array(str.length);
    var fifthBit = 1 << 5; // or 32 if you prefer :)

    for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
        var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);

        // check if character belongs to a-z or A-Z first
        if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 ||
            charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) {

            // here we can safely swap without generating an invisible char
            charCode ^= fifthBit;
        }

        swappedCaseCharBuffer[i] = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    }

    return swappedCaseCharBuffer.join('');
}
```